# writing Jtextfield string data into an arraylist, and reading same data from arraylist to Jtextfields

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been scouring the internet for answers to my problem. I have found some good advice and have changed my original code, but I am yet to discover the answer to my initial problem.

I am trying to take string data from a series of Jtextfields and writing them to an arraylist, and then in turn taking the written data from the arraylist and transfering it to the same text fields.

```
public class Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {


  public ArrayList<Personal> personalList;
  public ArrayList<Business> businessList;
  public ArrayList<Personal> displayPersonalList;
  public ArrayList<Business> displayBusinessList;      


public Form() {

    initArrayLists();

}

private void initArrayLists(){
    personalList = new ArrayList<Personal>();
    businessList = new ArrayList<Business>();
    displayPersonalList = new ArrayList<Personal>();
    displayBusinessList = new ArrayList<Business>();
}
```

this is my submit button that writes to the arraylists.

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                             
    if (contactTypeLabel.getText().equals("Personal Contact")){
        Personal p = new Personal();
        p.first = firstNameTF.getText();
        p.last = lastNameTF.getText();
        p.address = addressTF.getText();
        p.s = stateTF.getText();
        p.zip = zipTF.getText();
        p.phone = phoneTF.getText();
        p.email = emailTF.getText();
        personalList.add(p);

        Personal d = new Personal();
        d.first = firstNameTF.getText();
        displayPersonalList.add(p);

        resetTextFields();

    }else if (contactTypeLabel.getText().equals("Business Contact")){
        Business b = new Business();
        b.first = firstNameTF.getText();
        b.last = lastNameTF.getText();
        b.address = addressTF.getText();
        b.s = stateTF.getText();
        b.zip = zipTF.getText();
        b.phone = phoneTF.getText();
        b.email = emailTF.getText();
        businessList.add(b);

        Business d = new Business();
        d.first = firstNameTF.getText();
        displayBusinessList.add(d);

        resetTextFields();

    }

}
```

here is the code to change to display mode, with a combobox that should populate for accessing the arraylist to fill the textfields with selected data

```
private void displayPersonalButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                      
    personalFieldViewer();
    submitButton.setVisible(false);
    displayComboBox.setVisible(true);
    clearTextFields();

    for (Object item : displayPersonalList) {
    displayComboBox.addItem(item);
    }

}
```

this is the code for the combobox action and code to fill the text fields

```
private void displayComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                
    int x;
    switch (displayComboBox.getSelectedIndex()){
        case 0: 
            for (x = 0; x < x + 8; x ++) {
            switch (x){
                case 0 :firstNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 1 :lastNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 2 :addressTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 3 :stateTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 4 :zipTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 5 :phoneTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 6 :dobTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 7 :emailTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                    }
            }
            break;
        case 1: 
            for (x = 8; x < x + 8; x ++) {
            switch (x){
                case 8 :firstNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 9 :lastNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 10 :addressTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 11 :stateTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 12 :zipTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 13 :phoneTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 14 :dobTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 15 :emailTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                    }
            }
            break;
        case 2: 
            for (x = 16; x < x + 8; x ++) {
            switch (x){
                case 16 :firstNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 17 :lastNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 18 :addressTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 19 :stateTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 20 :zipTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 21 :phoneTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 22 :dobTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                case 23 :emailTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
                    break;
                    }
            }
            break;            


    }
}
```

here are the classes that hold the variables for the arraylists.

```
public class Contacts {
    public String first, last, address, s, zip, phone, email;

}

public class Personal extends Contacts{
   public String dob; 

}

public class Business extends Contacts{
    public String title, organization;

}
```

when I alternately try to fill the arraylists with *.add(textfield.getText()); Java will not allow this as well as using variables first=firstNameTF.getText(); then *.add(first); I get the same error message...

Please try to refrain from being negative, and I have read the API regarding arraylists. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arraylist declarations has type either Personal or Business. So these list cant add a string value. So when you say `personalList.add(textfield.getText());` its actually trying to add String object to a list that can contain only Personal object.

Secondly the for loop inside `displayComboBoxActionPerformed()` method results in an infinite loop. `for (x = 0; x < x + 8; x ++)`. Insted of having different for loops and switch statements you could do something like

```
private void displayComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    if(displayComboBox.getSelectedIndex() > -1){
        int start = displayComboBox.getSelectedIndex() * 8;
        for (int x = start; x < start + 8; x ++) {
            firstNameTF.setText(personalList.get(x).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just figured the string assignment to the arraylist myself. Thank you this solved all the problems I was having.